# Custom git server to get user input when pushing

Tags: git

Is there anyway to prompt user for input? This is example:

Wen user push to remote repository, server will accept all pushed data and perform a build/test job, if build success, server will accept push and do something, if build fail, server will prompt user about errors and ask for user want to create a ticket or not...

How can we build a git server like that? The most important part is how can we prompt user in pushing console window?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do anything you want with the custom scripts that get used as [a hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks). Specifically in your case:

> "pre-receive and post-receive
>
> The first script to run when handling a push from a client is pre-receive. It takes a list of references that are being pushed from stdin; if it exits non-zero, none of them are accepted. You can use this hook to do things like make sure none of the updated references are non-fast-forwards; or to check that the user doing the pushing has create, delete, or push access or access to push updates to all the files they’re modifying with the push.
>
> The post-receive hook runs after the entire process is completed and can be used to update other services or notify users. It takes the same stdin data as the pre-receive hook. Examples include e-mailing a list, notifying a continuous integration server, or updating a ticket-tracking system — you can even parse the commit messages to see if any tickets need to be opened, modified, or closed. This script can’t stop the push process, but the client doesn’t disconnect until it has completed; so, be careful when you try to do anything that may take a long time."

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is a hook.
Git provides many [hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks) to be implemented on the server-side.

I never used that, actually I have a server with [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) that runs the jobs to do the build checking for changes on the git repo every 10 min (don't ask me why, I didn't work on that :P).